# Set a variable within an if statement in batch

Tags: batch-file

I have a code snippet from a .bat file that doesn't seem to be functioning properly. The intention is to have the user set a variable (to K) for this snippet, but once I attempt to set the second variable (M or A) *within the if statement*, the variable %ufileType% is never set. Is this due to some syntax error or logic?

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
title Clean Install

ECHO Enter K:
SET /P uPrograms=
IF %uPrograms%==K (
  ECHO Change key to .mdb or .accdb? [M/A]
    SET /P !uFileType!=
    ECHO !uFileType!
    IF !uFileType!==M (
        ECHO Changing keys from .accdb to .mdb
    )
  IF !uFileType!==A (
    ECHO Changing keys from .accdb to .mdb
  )
) ELSE (
    ECHO Value not K
)

EXIT /B 0
```

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: `SET /P !uFileType!=` - I think that should be `SET /P uFileType=`.

Comment: @melpomene Changing that line does not appear to change anything, the var still does not set. Thanks though.

Comment: I just tried it and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    SET /P !uFileType!=
```

This line is wrong. It should be

```
    SET /P uFileType=
```

You only use `%...%` or `!...!` when you want to get the value of a variable, not when you want to set it.

Comment: Sorry, checked it again with some pauses, and works great. Thanks!